# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field memberVariable with private variable

Tags: java, enums

I created a enum with one private member variable.
When i try to access the member variable the compiles states 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field memberVariable'.

If the variable is not private (e.g. protected or package protected) it compiles fine. I don't understand what the scope of the variable has to do with the type (static, non static) of the implemented abstract function.

Can someone enlighten me?

```
public enum EnumWithAbstractMethodAndMembers {
    TheOneAndOnly(1) {
        @Override
        public int addValue(final int value) {
            return memberVariable + value;
        }
    };

    private final int memberVariable;

    private EnumWithAbstractMethodAndMembers(final int memberVariable) {
        this.memberVariable = memberVariable;
    }

    abstract int addValue(int value);

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error message is confusing.

The problem is that when you give an enum value code, you are creating an anonymous sub class of the enum. (Its class will be `EnumWithAbstractMethodAndMembers$1`) A sub-class cannot access the private members of its super-class, however nested classes can via generated accessor method.  You should be able to access the private field, and the error message it gives you appears to be mis-leading.

BTW You can use this, but you shouldn't need to IMHO.

```
    public int addValue(final int value) {
        return super.memberVariable + value;
    }
```

---

Here is a shorter example I will log as a bug in the error message as it doesn't lead to a solution to the problem.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    One {
        public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
            // error: non-static variable memberVariable cannot be referenced from a static context
            return memberVariable;
        }

        public int getMemberVariable2OK() {
            return memberVariable2;
        }

        public int getMemberVariableOK() {
            return super.memberVariable;
        }
    };

    private final int memberVariable = 1;
    final int memberVariable2 = 1;
}
```

---

Based on Tom Hawkin's feedback, this example gets the same error message.

```
public class MyNotEnum {
    // this is the static context in which the anonymous is created
    public static final MyNotEnum One = new MyNotEnum() {
        public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
            // error: non-static variable memberVariable cannot be referenced from a static context
            return memberVariable;
        }

        public int getMemberVariableOK() {
            return super.memberVariable;
        }
    };
    private final int memberVariable = 1;
}
```

for comparison

```
public class MyNotEnum {
    public class NestedNotEnum extends MyNotEnum {
        public int getMemberVariableFailes() {
            // compiles just fine.
            return memberVariable;
        }

        public int getMemberVariableOK() {
            return super.memberVariable;
        }
    }
    private final int memberVariable = 1;
}
```

Comment: Sound's reasonable. Thx for the answer and the hint with 'super.'!

Comment: I have logged it as a `javac` bug.

Comment: They say it should be visible in a couple of days. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7119746 I have noticed Oracle accept my bugs **much** faster than Sun did.

Comment: It's not a bug. It is mentioned in Java Puzzlers somewhere. Compiler bugs usually aren't. / A subclass can access the member variables of its super class, if the super class is (or is within) the same outerclass.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, The explains why the second case works.  IMHO, It doesn't explain why the first cases doesn't compile or why the error message complains about a non-static context.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey See my answer for further details.

Comment: For you current last piece of code, `NestedNotEnum` instances have two instances of `memberVariable` available to them. What might be surprising (and why the error is useful) is that the two get methods return the values of the variables in two different instances.

Comment: You can make the member variable `protected` instead of `private` to avoid the issue too if you find using `super` unpleasant.

Answer (score 4):

A similar issue is covered by Puzzle 92 (Twisted Pair) in [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) by Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter.

It's nothing special about enums. Any anonymous (or local) inner class in a static context will do. The rules are that the outer class is considered before the super class. This makes a lot of sense for such classes in a non-static context. If changing the context to static changed which variable was looked up, the is the potential to introduce "confusion" at runtime (C++ is much more aggressive with this kind of rule).

An inner class that extends an outer class has access to the private instance fields of the outer class, whether through `this` or some other instance.

As we are allowed access, we need to somehow specify we want to go through the inner this rather than outer this. As Peter Lawrey points out `super.member` will do. You can also select the inner this, and then use that expression:

```
        return ((EnumWithAbstractMethodAndMembers)this).memberVariable + value;
```

Or

```
        EnumWithAbstractMethodAndMembers innerThis = this;
        return innerThis.memberVariable + value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of error is : **you are trying to make reference to private variable (`memberVariable`) of super class from inner implementation class.**

To make error free code you can do either of following :

- you have to use `super.memberVariable` since `memberVariable` is **not local** to `TheOnlyAndOnly()`
- you can make `int memberVariable` **public**.
- you can do:

  ```
  TheOneAndOnly(1) {
      int memberVariable=4;
      @Override
      public int addValue(final int value) {
          return memberVariable + value;
      }
  };
  ```