# Enum's anonymous implementation cannot reference the Enum's private static toString with argument

Tags: java, enums

Given this example code...

```
package example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.X.getValue());
    }

    private enum MyEnum {
        X(){
            @Override
            String getValue() {
                return toString("XYZ"); //error here
            }
        };

        abstract String getValue();

        private static String toString(String output) {
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

The following compiler error is produced:

```
Error:(12, 40) java: method toString in class java.lang.Enum<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

IntelliJ comes with a different issue: `toString` from `toString("XYZ")` is underlined with red, and the message "'toString(java.lang.String)' has private access in 'example.Main.MyEnum'" is shown, with the solution to "Make 'MyEnum.toString' package-private".

What's weird to me, is that any of the following fixes this issue:

- Calling the method via enum reference: `X.toString("XYZ")`.
- Calling the method via class reference: `MyEnum.toString("XYZ")`.
- Calling the method via super: `super.toString("XYZ")`. (But `this.toString("XYZ")` doesn't work)
- Making the method package-private or public
- Naming the method "toString2"

Now, for any production code, I'd probably name the method something else (probably something more descriptive to what I'd do with it) and move on, but still I'm left wondering, why does this happen? And why are the error messages from IntelliJ and javac different?

This question is probably similar to [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field memberVariable with private variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442874/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field-membervariable-with-priva), but I feel it doesn't fully explain the issue - why does renaming work?

Comment: @Michael I'm not looking for a quick fix, I'm looking for an explanation; why do I need to add MyEnum in front just because the method is named "toString"? The argument alone should be enough to make the difference between the default toString (0 arguments) and my own toString (1 argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this problem is not specific to enums. It is applicable to any inner class. I have refactored your example to remove the enum, which demonstrates the same problem with both an inner class and an anonymous inner class.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main() {
            {
                System.out.println(toString("XYZ")); // same error
            }  
        };
    }

    class Foo {
        {
            System.out.println(toString("XYZ")); // same error
        }
    }

    private static String toString(String output) {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Is explained in the JLS [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1):

> **Example 6.5.7.1-1. Simple Method Names**
>
> The following program demonstrates the role of scoping when
>   determining which method to invoke.
>
> ```
> class Super {
>     void f2(String s)       {}
>     void f3(String s)       {}
>     void f3(int i1, int i2) {}
> }
>
> class Test {
>     void f1(int i) {}
>     void f2(int i) {}
>     void f3(int i) {}
>
>     void m() {
>         new Super() {
>             {
>                 f1(0);  // OK, resolves to Test.f1(int)
>                 f2(0);  // compile-time error
>                 f3(0);  // compile-time error
>             }
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> For the invocation `f1(0)`, only one method named f1 is in scope. It is the method `Test.f1(int)`, whose declaration is in scope
>   throughout the body of Test including the anonymous class declaration.
>   [§15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) chooses to search in class Test since the anonymous class
>   declaration has no member named `f1`. Eventually, `Test.f1(int)` is
>   resolved.
>
> For the invocation `f2(0)`, two methods named `f2` are in scope. First,
>   the declaration of the method `Super.f2(String)` is in scope throughout
>   the anonymous class declaration. Second, the declaration of the method
>   `Test.f2(int)` is in scope throughout the body of Test including the
>   anonymous class declaration. (Note that neither declaration shadows
>   the other, because at the point where each is declared, the other is
>   not in scope.) [§15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) chooses to search in class Super because it
>   has a member named `f2`. However, `Super.f2(String)` is not applicable to
>   `f2(0)`, so a compile-time error occurs. Note that class `Test` is not
>   searched.
>
> For the invocation `f3(0)`, three methods named `f3` are in scope. First
>   and second, the declarations of the methods `Super.f3(String)` and
>   `Super.f3(int,int)` are in scope throughout the anonymous class
>   declaration. Third, the declaration of the method `Test.f3(int)` is in
>   scope throughout the body of Test including the anonymous class
>   declaration. [§15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) chooses to search in class `Super` because it has
>   a member named `f3`. However, `Super.f3(String)` and `Super.f3(int,int)` are
>   not applicable to `f3(0)`, so a compile-time error occurs. Note that
>   class `Test` is not searched.
>
> Choosing to search a nested class's superclass hierarchy before the
>   lexically enclosing scope is called the "comb rule" ([§15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)).

Comment: Can you expain why in eclipse OP code works and also your first System.out.println works?

Comment: @user7294900 Eclipse compiler is a different implementation to `javac`. Either the Eclipse authors decided to "improve" this behaviour deliberately, or it is an obscure enough use-case such that no one noticed the difference.

Comment: Your example differs from the `enum` case, as there, the nested class is also a subclass of the outer class. Both `toString` methods are available within the superclass, but apparently, `javac` assumes that the `private` method is accessible (`super.toString("XYZ")` would work), but not inherited. The difference [has been noticed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=325157), but it took the JDK team four years to decide that Eclipse is wrong, closing [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6986202), and apparently, no-one told the Eclipse team to re-open their bug…

Comment: @Holger Nice sleuthing. Give it another 10 years, maybe it'll get a fix.